# Functioning of VLOOKUP as Matrix Formula

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am using a VLOOKUP-function within a Matrix-Formula. This combination allows me to use 2 criteria instead of just one. (also see picture)

{=VLOOKUP("Hamburg";IF(C2:C5="Tom";B2:D5;““);3;0)}

**To be clear: The Formula works fine!**

My question however is: How does it work? Is my understanding correct that, if the formula "finds" Tom in e.g. C4, only the matrix B4 to D4 is used for the VLOOKUP-Function? Since is does not find "Hamburg" in B4 to D4, it will return nothing and the MAtrix-Formula proceeds to C5?

kind regards and thank you in advance for helping me understand
sombrero

***VLOOKUP-Example:***

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to understand a nested formula like yours is to break it down into steps, you can either do this manually taking each piece of the formula one by one or using the formula evaluation tool in Excel. In your case, the Array Formula logic is **applied to the nested IF that's inside the VlookUp** - there, where it doesn't find a match for "Tom" it returns a `blank space`, and where it does, it returns the original value, see my example:

[image: Example of nested IF logic]

The easiest way to evaluate this is going in the ribbon to `Formulas>Formula Auditing>Evaluate Formula`, you'll see the following popup where you can clic through "Evaluate" and see the formula logic step by step:

[image: Evaluate Formula popup]

Comment: However, for your example I would recomend using this instead, where you don't even need an array formula: `=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B5="Hamburg")*(C2:C5="Tom")*D2:D5)`

Comment: Thank you very much Fernando, that - especially the "evaluate formula"-tool -really helped!